# How should I deal with contexts using `<canvas>`?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I already have three contexts on this page. I have this section here from context 2 which gives a shadow to some text. But it's also giving a shadow to everything else in context2, is there a way to isolate stuff within a context? Or should I just create another context just for this text, and another one for the next thing I want to do?

```
drawArc(ctx2, 15, 30, "white", 0, 360);
ctx2.fillStyle = "rgb(80,80,80)";
ctx2.font = '24px sans-serif';
ctx2.shadowColor = "gray";
ctx2.shadowOffsetX = 2;
ctx2.shadowOffsetY = 2;
text = 'whateva';
ctx2.fillText(text, 50, 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're modifying the context for a specific temporary purpose (like your shadowing), just wrap the temporary context modifications in context.save() and context.restore().

Then the temporary context changes will be automatically reversed with context.restore();

```
// save ctx2 in its current state
ctx2.save()

drawArc(ctx2, 15, 30, "white", 0, 360);
ctx2.fillStyle = "rgb(80,80,80)";
ctx2.font = '24px sans-serif';
ctx2.shadowColor = "gray";
ctx2.shadowOffsetX = 2;
ctx2.shadowOffsetY = 2;
text = 'whateva';
ctx2.fillText(text, 50, 50);

// return ctx2 to its pre-modified state
ctx2.restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to draw everything before the text and just before drawing the text set the shadow and then draw the text ?